# How to create a youtube embedder?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I created a video hosting site
I would like to create a form on my site where you post the youtube embed code and the video is played in jw player on my site and gets added to playlist, what should I look for to create such form?

**EDIT:**

@Marc B:

okay sir, is there any tutorials out there or anything just to see how it works? I mean how to create the form? I have no problem using youtube player lol :D

Comment: If you're embedding a youtube video on your page using their provided embedding code, you'd be using the Youtube player, not your own.

Comment: @Marc B okay no problem, how to do it then? :D

Comment: Please don't chat in your question.

Comment: Click the 'embed' button on any youtube video page. it gives you a snippet of HTML you can paste in anywhere. Your form would take this snippet and insert it on your "player" page, which'd then simply be a container for the Youtube .swf movie player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?
$yt_video = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfgdUfDgCq8"; //OR   $yt_video = $_GET['id']; // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfgdUfDgCq8

if (preg_match('%(?:youtube\.com/(?:user/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $yt_video, $match))
 {

/* regex works with:
    http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
    http://www.youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
    http://www.youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    http://www.youtube.com/e/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    http://www.youtube.com/user/username#p/u/11/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
    http://www.youtube.com/?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
*/

$jw = <<< EOF

<script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer.js'></script>

<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf',
    'file': '{$yt_video}',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '470',
    'height': '320'
  });
</script>
EOF;

echo $jw;

}else{ 
echo "invalid youtube video";    
}
?>
```

Download [jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) and change `player.swf` and `jwplayer.js` locations. GL :)

Comment: I'm gonna try that right now, I like the script lol, I don't care if your answer is correct or not, I am a stackoverflow user because i like to see these answers, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that youtube has a template for embeded videos.

Comment: something tells me that your answer is the correct one, i can't prove it yet so I'm gonna try to do it like Marc B's way, but i don't know, I feel like you are correct, although i can't find the template or any documentation regarding that